# Change touch bar settings programmatically via Terminal in MacOS High Sierra

Tags: macos, terminal, nstouchbar

I'd like to be able to toggle between 'Touch bar shows F1, F2, etc keys' and 'Touch bar shows expanded control strip' using defaults.write

I've tried the following:

1. I saved 'defaults read' to a file, changed the touch bar setting, then saved 'defaults read' to another file, then compared the two files to see the differences.
2. The only difference seems to be that `com.apple.touchbar.agent PresentationModeGlobal` switches between `fullControlStrip` and `functionKeys`

However, when I apply that change successfully using `defaults write com.apple.touchbar.agent PresentationModeGlobal functionKeys`, it doesn't change my touch bar.

Is there a reason `defaults write` isn't having the desired effect?

Answer (score 5):

You've gotten it correct. All that's left to do is to restart the touch bar.

```
pkill "Touch Bar agent"; killall "ControlStrip";
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired on @KitchenTable99 I created the following solution.

```
touch "$HOME/Desktop/Toggle TouchBar Presentation Mode.command"
```

Create an executable command in the Desktop (or wherever you prefer). Then add this content to it:

```
function toggleTouchBarPresentationMode() {
   presentationMode="$(defaults read com.apple.touchbar.agent 'PresentationModeGlobal')"

   if [[ "appWithControlStrip" == $presentationMode ]]; then
       targetMode=fullControlStrip
   else
       targetMode=appWithControlStrip
   fi

   defaults write com.apple.touchbar.agent PresentationModeGlobal $targetMode; 
   # restart the control strip
   killall "ControlStrip";
}

toggleTouchBarPresentationMode
```

You can replace the desired behaviour by replacing the modes you want to toggle.